# Recursive function variable confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
megaList = []
clmsArrow = [[3],[2,3,4],[1,3,5],[3],[3],[3],[3]]

def columnState(y,amnt):
    "-1 for all values in a list of lists"
    megaList.append(y)
    print(y)
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[i])):
            y[i][j] -= 1
            if y[i][j] == 0:
                y[i][j] = 5

    if amnt != 1:
        return columnState(y,amnt-1)

columnState(clmsArrow,5)
print('\n')
for x in megaList:
    print(x)

''Output''

[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 4], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
[[1], [5, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
[[5], [4, 5, 1], [3, 5, 2], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
[[4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 1], [4], [4], [4], [4]]


[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Why can't I write out to global variable (list) properly? All I get is the same first function input times five

As seen in the output inside function everything is alright, but when I try to add the same variable to a list outside the function something goes wrong

Comment: Inside function you need to write: ```global megaList``` (which you also need to define, before you go into function, as an empty list I suppose)

Comment: Another solution would be to wrap this function in a class and make `megaList` a **class attribute**.  This means you don't have to use a global, and all methods in the class can access it.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, there's no need to mark a name as global if it's never rebound inside the function (if there's no assignment like `megaList = 'whatever'`)

Comment: "Why can't I write out to global variable (list) properly?" What makes you think you can't do this? Can you show some example output and explain what you want it to be instead.

Comment: Also read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get some tips about debugging your code.

Comment: Alternatively, declare `megaList` locally and return its value on each recursive call. Better yet, write this as a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you keep adding *references* to `y` in your `mega_list`. And if you change `y` you also change *all* the references to `y`. For example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [a, a]
print(b)
a[0] = 99
print(b)
```

which prints

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
[[99, 2], [99, 2]]
```

notice how `b` changed even though I only change `a`. This is because `b` contains *references* to `a` instead of *copies*.

To fix this in your code you can simply add this to start of your function

```
y = deepcopy(y)
```

you'll need to also add

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

the reason you need `deepcopy` instead of simply doing `y[:]` is because your `y` is ` nested list i.e. all the lists inside of it are also just references to other lists and those also need to be copied.

Finally, the reason you are getting back to your original value is because you made `amnt` equal `5` and your function does nothing if you run if `5` times because of

```
        if y[i][j] == 0:
            y[i][j] = 5
```

so they are changing, they're just landing up back where they started. If you run

```
columnState(clmsArrow, 4)
```

for example then you'll see the change i.e. you get

```
[[3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 4], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
[[1], [5, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
[[5], [4, 5, 1], [3, 5, 2], [5], [5], [5], [5]]

[[4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 1], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
[[4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 1], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
[[4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 1], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
[[4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 1], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
```